# Incorrect syntax near 'End' , not letting run the query nor create procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

Not letting me create the procedure, nor not letting run this query please help.

It's not letting run the query .. this is just a section of query

Comment: What a mess.  If you indent your code, you'll see that `end`s are missing for your `case` expressions.

Answer (score 1):

You had a few things wrong, you didnt need the parens, you were missing an End Statement, and your indents made it hard to read, and you are missing your FROM statement, so I put FROM and added tableName you need to fill this in.

```
  create proc  [dbo].[a_test]

   as
   begin


      SELECT top 10 
      file_ty = '5',
      cno= rtrim(ltrim(adm.AccountNumber)),
      Column3='',
      Column4='',
      Admit_Date =  
        CASE 
            WHEN RegistrationType_MisRegTypeID <>'IN' 
            THEN '' 
            ELSE CONVERT(varchar(10),replace(convert(varchar(10),adm.AdmitDateTime,101),'/ ','')) 
        END,
    Point_Of_Origin = 
        CASE 
            WHEN RegistrationType_MisRegTypeID='IN' then 
                CASE 
                    WHEN AdmitSource='CIR' then '2'
                    WHEN AdmitSource='BSH' then '2'
                    ELSE ''
                END     
        END

        FROM dbo.TableName

END
```